# Show Google Places search controller only on first viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, uisearchcontroller

I am using the Google Places API to provide autocomplete for my navigation app. However, following the Google docs, I have put the search controller in the `UINavigationBar`, but when I go to another ViewController in the navigation stack, instead of showing that `ViewController` title in the `UINavigationBar`, it still shows the search controller.

Following the docs, I add the search controller to the navigation bar from the initial ViewController like this:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = _searchController.searchBar;
```

Comment: Use a UISeach bar instead. You can even add it via storyboard as well. It's easy and a better way.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I combine it with the Google Places autocomplete?

Comment: That's default. If you want a custom UI, then you need to create a custom Google Place autocomplete using GMSAutocompleteFetcher and GMSAutocompletePrediction. https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_a_full-screen_control

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/TarasRoshko/TRAutocompleteView this is exactly what you need

Comment: I am sure there is an easier solution, but thanks!

Comment: Just look at the technique used in the library i you will understand what you need